# Working with empty objects in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of arrays that I am trying to pull values from. The problem is that I get an undefined error when it hits an empty array.

Here is the array I'm working with:

```
 data = [[Object { myvar=null}], [Object { myvar="testval"}], [], [], []]
```

Here is the javascript I'm using to get all myvar values:

```
myarr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i][0].myvar);
    if (data[i][0].myvar) {
        dep = data[i][0].myvar;
        if (dep != null) {
            myarr.push(dep);
        }
    }
}
```

The console.log looks like:

```
   null
   testval
   Error: data[i][0] is undefined
```

So it breaks when it reaches the first []. How could I remove all the empty arrays before the for loop? Or have the for loop not die when it hits an empty array? Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code that put the empty array there ?

Comment: The third element in `data` Array is an empty Array. So when your reach `i=2` (which is the third element), `data[i]` is empty. So there is no `data[i][0]

Comment: check my answer it even checks for empty objects and arrays while being shortest

Comment: and i am pretty sure your syntax is wrong for declaring data array. you dont put object {..}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  can simply check whether the current item is empty:

```
if (data[i].length === 0) continue;
```

Comment: That's it... In this case it was !== 0. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add this as an answer..  In javascript, I believe `null == false`.  So you can also do something like this:

```
if(data[i][0])
   //it's not null or undefined, do some work
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure data[i] is an array and it has at least 1 item first :

```
var i, item, myarr = [],
    isNotEmptyArray = function(a) {
        return Object.prototype.toString.call(a) === '[object Array]' && a.length > 0;
    };

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    item = data[i];
    if (isNotEmptyArray(item) && item[0].myvar) {
        console.log(item[0].myvar);
        dep = item[0].myvar;
        if (dep != null) {
            myarr.push(dep);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why create a monster like this when you can get the same result with `data.forEach(function(e){ (e[0]) && myarr.push(e); });`

Comment: Not all browsers support forEach (well, mainly IE), I was just fixing his code.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].length !== 0) continue;
    if (data[i][0].myvar) {
        dep = data[i][0].myvar;
        if (dep != null) {
            myarr.push(dep);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best and cleanest way to do it.

```
data.forEach(function(e){
    if(Object.keys(e).length) myarr.push(e);
});
```

**take a look** http://jsfiddle.net/8zfZd/ open console to see object.

[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

to make it even shorter...

```
data.forEach(function(e){ (e[0]) && myarr.push(e); });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cgg6j/

Answer (score -1):

Add this loop before your loop to clear the empty arrays:

```
var i = 0;
while (true) {
    if (i == data.length)
        break;
    if (data[i].length == 0)
        data.splice(i, 1);
    else
        ++i;
}
```

Comment: Why looping twice? You can check `if (data[i].length == 0)` inside the same loop

Comment: @matewka The OP specifically asked for a way to remove the empty objects before the for loop. The code I supplied is tested and correct.

Comment: Though he asked, it doesn't mean it is correct. I think you could suggest a better answer than just fulfilling OP's request.

Comment: @matewka Ok, but consider that OP clearly didn't know how to remove elements of an array, so the answer may have value for him later even if he doesn't use it in this particular case.